# Getting "undefined" for array in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined` for the following code:

```
constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {};
      this.state['addEventPartial'] = false;
      files: [];
}

onDrop(files) {
    console.log('Received files: ', files);
    return this.setState({
      files: files
    });
  }
```

I am calling the function from:

```
<Dropzone ref="dropzone" multiple={true} disableClick={false} onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
   <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
   <img src={this.state.files.file.preview} />
</Dropzone>
```

The component seems to work otherwise, on the console I am getting:

```
Received files:
    Array[1]0: 
        FilelastModified: 1435886629000
        lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 03 2015 06:23:49 GMT+0500 (MVT)
        name: "10891478_10203743822177760_9162320962035940276_n.jpg"
        preview: "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/1fa46173-9630-43aa-a73c-fadced37c9d0"
        size: 82856
        type: "image/jpeg"
```

I cant seem to access the files array. I am not sure what is wrong, am I doing this right? Thanks

Comment: On line 4 of your constructor you have `files: []`, typo or is this the cause?

Comment: Also `files` would be an array if you fixed that and wouldn't have a `file` property either.

Comment: I tried looping through the files array as well but I can't seem to access it either.

Comment: There is no files array. `files:` is a label, and `[]` is a literal array as a statement, so it's just created and then forgotten. You need to put it in the state object: `this.state.files = [];`.